# Setting up Spring 4 RestTemplate to use SSL (JKS)

Tags: spring, ssl, resttemplate

All, I am attempting to set up Spring's RestTemplate to allow for SSL calls to partner's web services.  My setup is:

- Java 1.7
- Spring version 4.1
- Httpclient version 4.3
- Tomcat 7.0.54

I am trying to leverage the new feature of the 3.x servlet-api.jar (comes with Tomcat 7) and Spring 4 that allows my Spring configuration to be completely annotation/code driven instead of having multiple XML configuration files (as of right now my web.xml file is completely empty).  So far I have:

My base configuration class, pretty straight forward

```
package com.config;

[imports]

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.application")
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config {

}
```

And my web initialization class.  I'm pulling in my certs and reading them into Resource objects, but so far am not doing anything with them.  I also have it set up so that I'm able to make rest calls into my application (not that this is relevant to my issue).

```
package com.config;

[imports]

@Configuration
public class WebApplication implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(com.config.Config.class);

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

        Resource trustStore = ctx.getResource("file:" + System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"));

        Resource keyStore = ctx.getResource("file:" + System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore"));

        String trustStorePassword = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword")
        String keyStorePassword = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword")
    }
}
```

It appears a decent amount has changed from Spring 3 to Spring 4 so that existing examples on how to set up the RestTemplate using SSL is no longer valid.  On top of that I've been combing the web for an example on how to do this using Java/annotations instead of xml files but so far have been unable to discover anything out there.  I've made several different attempts to configure a RestTemplate object with SSL myself without any luck.  Does anyone have a good example or link to an example on how to attempt to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like I found a good example that got me 95% of the way there (the other 5% was just configuration on my end to make it work within our system).  Look at how this developer implemented FactoryBean for Spring's RestTemplate and don't forget to create a ClientHttpRequestFactory with your sslContext/HttpClient and create your RestTemplate with that.  I apologize for not posting my code but we develop on a closed network.

https://hjpetstore.googlecode.com/svn-history/r40/trunk/hjpetstore2.0/src/main/java/org/pprun/common/web/rest/client/SslRestTemplateFactoryBean.java